# In Firefox (2 or 3), what is the chrome:// path for the "Website Certified by Unknown Authority" XUL dialog?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

Another angle:
how do I browse all the XUL for a given chrome path, e.g.

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Dev_:_Firefox_Chrome_URLs has a listing but seems to be out of date.

Answer (score 2):

At least in Firefox 3, `chrome://global/content/netError.xhtml?e=nssBadCert&u=` is what you're looking for.  `netError.xhtml` handles all sorts of connection problems, and modifies itself depending on what the actual error is.

Answer (score 1):

Mozilla [`chrome://` URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/The_Chrome_URL) refer to actual files located in a .jar file in some fairly well-defined places.

The main browser (chrome://browser/content/...) itself:

```
{where you installed Firefox}/chrome/browser.jar
```

Firefox add-ons:

```
{your profile directory}/extensions/{extension id}/chrome/content/...
```

where `{your profile directory}`, on Windows XP at least, is

```
c:\Documents and Settings\{your username}\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\{your profile name, usually ends in .default}
```